# How to find the file location of int.d scripts in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, startup, init

I need location of a init.d script.

I am using `service cinder-api start` to start the service

Other init scripts are located at `/etc/init.d/` location. But this service is not found in that location , its starting and stopping using `service cinder-api start`, so there must be some init script for that.

How can I find the absolute path of that init script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the usual suspects are:

1. `/etc/init`
2. `/etc/init.d`
3. `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`
4. `/etc/default`

(as documented in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)